# perl modules missing after upgrading to 22.04

Tags: perl

Yesterday I upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04
the upgrade went fairly smoothly.

However, after the upgrade, all the perl modules I had installed were no longer installed.

Is this because Perl was re-installed ?

Answer (score 1):

Modules are built and installed *for a specific version of perl*. Ubuntu 20.04 uses perl 5.30.0, whereas Ubuntu 22.04 uses perl 5.34.0.

If you installed the modules from Ubuntu packages then I would expect that you'd get updated versions of them for the new perl when you upgrade the OS. But if you installed them using `CPAN.pm` or `cpanm` then the OS doesn't know about them so can't do that for you.

In general, in the perl community it is recommended that you don't use the perl that comes with the OS (and this applies to any OS, not just Ubuntu) for this very reason. It's better to use something like `perlbrew` to build your own perl, and to then use `cpanm` to install modules in it.